# How to use an alias inside an include where condition using Sequelize

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

A table contains 2 user id cols, userOneId and userTwoId. My user id could be in either col. I'd like to get all rows where my userId is in either col, and also include the associated object of the other user.

Here's the latest attempt. I query where my id is in userOneId or userTwoId, make an alias for the other user id, otherUserId, with a case/when. Then use alias otherUserId in an include, to return the other user associated object.

```
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [{
        userOneId: userId,
      }, {
        userTwoId: userId,
      }]
    },
    attributes: [
      'id',
      [sequelize.literal("CASE WHEN \"userOneId\" = " + userId + " THEN \"userTwoId\" ELSE \"userOneId\" END"), 'otherUserId']
    ],
    include: {
      where: {
        id: '$otherUserId$'
      },
      model: sequelize.models.User,
      as: 'otherUser',
      attributes: [ 'id', 'name', ...
```

Model associations are:

```
    MyModel.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: 'userOne',
      foreignKey: 'userOneId'
    })

    MyModel.belongsTo(models.User, {
      as: 'userTwo',
      foreignKey: 'userTwoId'
    })

  User.hasMany(models.MyModel, {
    as: 'userOne',
    foreignKey: {
      name: 'userOneId',
      allowNull: false
    }
  })

  User.hasMany(models.MyModel, {
    as: 'userTwo',
    foreignKey: {
      name: 'userTwoId',
      allowNull: false
    }
  })
```

However, it errors with

> User is associated to MyModel multiple times. To identify the correct association, you must use the 'as' keyword to specify the alias of the association you want to include.

Any pointers on if or how to get this to work?